# Using JTR in Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, ubuntu-18.04, pdftotext

I am trying JTR to brute force a pdf file.

The password of pdf is like First 4 Letters Last 4 Number ex: ABCD1234 or ZDSC1977

I've downloaded the jumbo source code from github and using `pdf2john.pl` i've extracted the hash.

But now by reading the documentation it says i need to configure and install john which is not going to work in my case.

Cloud Functions or firebase functions does not allow `sudo apt get` installs. and that's the reasone we can't use tools like popple utils which includes amazing `pdftotext`.

How can i use JTR in cloud functions properly without need of installation ?

is there any portable or prebuilt for `ubuntu 18.04` version of `JTR` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to keep in mind that you can't arrange for packages to be installed on Cloud Functions instances. This due to your code doesn't run with root privileges.

If you need binaries to be available to your code deployed to Cloud Functions, you will have to build it yourself for Debian, and include the binaries in your functions directory so it gets deployed along with the rest of your code.

Even if you're able to do that, there's no guarantee it will work, because the Cloud Fucntions images may not include all the shared libraries required for the executables to work.

You can request that new packages be added to the runtime using the [Public Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=802601).

Otherway, you can use Cloud Run or Compute Engine.